# In-App Billing After Purchase

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I was wondering how I would be able to have my app remove the buttons for buying an item that a user has purchased in in-app billing. I could use sharedpreferences, but how would I go about doing that. This is the tutorial I used: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html.

Thanks

```
public Handler mTransactionHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Transaction complete");
            Log.i(TAG, "Transaction status: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.purchaseState);
            Log.i(TAG, "Item attempted purchase is: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);



    };     
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you followed the Dungeons example, you probably have implemented a ResponsHandler/PurchaseObserver ?

Somewhere in your code, you have registered a PurchaseObserver like this

```
ResponseHandler.register(purchaseObserver);
```

In the purchaseObserver, you override the method called

```
public void onPurchaseStateChange(...)
```

By using shared preferences you can keep track of the state of your app in that method. It is important to handle cancellations/refunds. If not, you're giving your stuff away for free. The code might look something like this

```
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = p.edit();
if (purchaseState == Consts.PurchaseState.CANCELED 
         || purchaseState ==   Consts.PurchaseState.REFUNDED) {
      e.putBoolean("PURCHASED", false);
} else if (purchaseState == Consts.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
      e.putBoolean("PURCHASED", true);
}
e.commit();
```

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but What would the purchaseState be? I am using the tutorial Blundell has provided. http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html

Comment: When following the Blundell tutorial, it looks like your code to update your preferences should go in teh mTransactionHandler inner class. The purchase states are  PURCHASED, (User was charged for the order), CANCELED (The charge failed on the server.) and REFUNDED (you refunded the purchase).

Comment: In the blundell code, what would the "purchaseState" stand as?

Comment: Can you look at my above code and tell me where to put what you said in it? I am guessing it would be in that area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to persist the bought items. Then inside onCreate() of your InAppActivity, do this :

```
if(settings.getBoolean("isAwesomeItemBought") {
   buyButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   buyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```