# In-app Billing and Ads

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I used the blundell in-app billing tutorial. Here is the link: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html. I am wondering how I can have someone donate, then have my app hide ads and keep it that way even after the person closes it. I am guessing I would be using SharedPreferences, but not sure about the rest. Please be as specific as possible and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to another SO post:

[In-App Billing After Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571246/in-app-billing-after-purchase)

SharedPreferences would look something like:

```
if(settings.getBoolean("isAwesomeItemBought") {
   buyButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   buyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Or I would really recommend Glenn's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571465/805031

Comment: Hi, that is actually another post that I made. I was having issues with where to put the sharedPreferences code since I was not using the Dungeons tutorial that he referred to, instead I used the Blundell tutorial which is in my post above. Hope you could help more! :)